# PHP : Why we are using " if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..'))

Tags: php

Why we are using  "  if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..'))  " in this code... 
Is using to find the file format is Windows or linux or mac ?

```
if (is_dir( "{$dir}/{$fname}" )) {
           if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..')) {
                echo "<u>Deleting Files in the Directory</u>: {$dir}/{$fname} <br />";
          deleteDir("$dir/$fname");
             }
 }
```

Comment: Beacuse '.' - current directory, '..' - parent directory

Answer (score 4):

`.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent one in a directory listing, so you are checking to avoid those when you process a directory list.

Answer (score 1):

"." refers to the current directory, and ".." refers to the parent directory.

So deleting `A/.` would delete `A/`, and deleting `A/B/..` would delete the parent of `B/`, `A/`.